# assigning text to UILabel using tag notation objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, tags, uilabel

I have created 5 `UILabels` using a for loop, I have set each items tag to the count of the loop. I am doing this in `viewdidload` method but then later am trying to assign a value to one of the `UILabels` using the .tag

here is how I create the UILabels

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  finishingCopyWidthLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i * quickSelectionBarSectionWidth)-180, 2.0, 100.0, 20.0)];
  finishingCopyWidthLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  finishingCopyWidthLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
  finishingCopyWidthLabel.text = @"";
  finishingCopyWidthLabel.tag = i;

[quickSelectionBar addSubview:finishingCopyWidthLabel];
    }
```

Then this is how I am trying to assign the text to the `UILable` however its not working, any help to get the assignment working would be awesome.

```
UILabel *fCopyWidthLabel = (UILabel *)[finishingCopyWidthLabel viewWithTag:1];
fCopyWidthLabel.text = [prefsDictionary objectForKey:@"QuickWidthOne"];
```

Comment: **Don't set the tag property for any element as** `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question updation, Instead of this `UILabel *fCopyWidthLabel = (UILabel *)[finishingCopyWidthLabel viewWithTag:1];` try this

```
UILabel *fCopyWidthLabel = (UILabel *)[quickSelectionBar viewWithTag:1];
```

Comment: I am getting an error now when I try to set the UILabel (as seen in the last line of code in my question) it says **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

Comment: I think, you have added some button to `quickSelectionBar` with tag 1. That's why, you getting that button. then when try to access `button.text`(in assumption of label), you got this error. Modify your button tag other than 1(better assign as 100). You will fix that issue quickly.

Comment: ahhh yes sorry you are correct, I understand how this works now. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
UILabel *fCopyWidthLabel = (UILabel *)[quickSelectionBar viewWithTag:1];
```

instead of

```
UILabel *fCopyWidthLabel = (UILabel *)[finishingCopyWidthLabel viewWithTag:1];
```

problem is you are referring the `UILabel` from the same Label (finishingCopyWidthLabel) instead of Parent view (quickSelectionBar).

Answer (score -1):

Please add method in your loop.

```
[self.view addSubview:finishingCopyWidthLabel];
```

Comment: added.. sorry it was already there I just forgot to add it to the question

Comment: @Rajesh This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Sorry guys.. I will take care next time.